# How can send and receive +5 volt through usb port D+ and D- pin

Tags: input, usb, signals, output

I have made an image comparing software. which start processing after clicking on a button.
But I want to get 5 volt signal from usb port using white(D-) and green(D+) pins for a millisecond and want to receive this signal in my c# code for initiating the process.

if image found difference then i want to send back a 5 volt signal to switch on an alarm.
is it better to send back a signal by using RS232 Pin no. 4?

by using

serialPort.DtrEnable = true;

Any idea please?????

Answer (score 0):

I have received signal by RS-232 by using

private void port_PinChanged(object sender, SerialPinChangedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (e.EventType == SerialPinChange.CDChanged)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CD Pin 1 changed");
            port.Close();
        }
        else if (e.EventType == SerialPinChange.CtsChanged)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CTS Pin 8 changed");
            port.Close();
        }
        else if (e.EventType == SerialPinChange.DsrChanged)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("DSR Pin 6 changed");
            port.Close();
        }
        else if (e.EventType == SerialPinChange.Ring)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("RI Pin 9 changed");
            port.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

But for sending output signal i m using

```
       using (SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600))
        {
            serialPort.Open();
            int a = 0;
            while (a<5)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
                serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                serialPort.DtrEnable = false;
                a++;
            }
  serialPort.Close();  }
```

but its not send output on pin 4 (DTR) or pin 7 (RTS) :(